# Jenkins 'build job' from groovy does not show any summary at actual job that was triggered from Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

The situation is: I'm running a job in another job using:

```
           stage('Test') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        try {
                            build job: 'ART', parameters: [
                                  string(name: 'DELAY_REQUEST', value:100),
                                  string(name: 'postman_collection_folder_names', value:ART_FOLDER_NAMES)]
```

The issue is; The 'ART' job runs, reports 'failed' or 'unstable' and that's it. No summary or anything else. When I navigate to the ART job, I don't see any info that it has run or whatever. Is this possible? The ART job sends an email with the results for example when run individually but not we see nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I wasn't triggering the job at all. Managed to fix it by adding a try catch with an echo of the error:

```
                       try {
                            build job: 'Post/ART', parameters: [
                                  string(name: 'DELAY_REQUEST', value:'100'),
                                  string(name: 'postman_collection_folder_names', value:ART_FOLDER_NAMES)], wait:true
                        } catch (e) {
                            echo e
}
```

then to get the right job name, I added `echo "$JOB_NAME"` in a shell script in the ART job and ran it. It started working after that.